# Coalesce a value in Meteor Jade

Tags: meteor, pug

In a template, I do this

```
if description
    p.editable= description
else
    p.editable
        | No description. Click to edit.
```

I wonder if there's a way to coalesce a value like in JavaScript:

```
p.editable #{description || 'Click to edit'}
```

But this is incorrect syntax in Jade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately jade doesn't support exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Best way would be to create a variable in your template like so:

```
- var desc = description || "Click to edit"
p.editable #{desc}
```